# Is there any way to add the argument values to the stack trace when using -fprof-auto-calls in GHC?

Tags: debugging, haskell, ghc, stack-trace

I'm trying to debug a complicated and recursive function using `traceStack`. My current approach is something similar to the following.

```
import Debug.Trace
smosh :: (Eq a, Show a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
smosh f s = traceStack (show (f, s)) smoshed
  where smoshed = ...
```

And later compiling it with `-prof -fprof-auto-calls` to get the full calling stack trace along with the variables each time I call `smosh`.

However, the stack trace is missing with which arguments I'm calling the rest of the functions of the stack trace (all of which are `Show`). Is there any simple way to add them that's nicer than adding `trace` to every other function?

Comment: I expect the answer to be simply “no”.

Comment: Perhaps the GHCi debugger could provide an alternative.